# Error while creating a custom entity record in mscrm 4.0

Tags: dynamics-crm-4

I am new to using CRM.I am facing a poblem while creating custome entity record using a console application.
This console application is run with a user having "**systemadministrator**" privileges.
When I call `objService.Creat(entity);` method

I am getting the following exception

`0x80042f09
  SecLib::CheckPrivilege failed. Returned hr = -2147209463, User: 395a4c3e-cf59-de11-8e41-001a646ad2f9`

Please let me know what caused this issue.

Thaks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because the actual webservice call is not being performed as a system administrator.

I would suggest using a [WhoAmI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb890244.aspx) query to check which user is actually being used, then you can correct their permissions.